# SplitViewController detail view transition

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, detailview

My problem is that my detail view gets presented instead of being pushed on compact devices, has anybody ever encountered this behaviour? if so, how did you get it to do the push?

My StoryBoard setting:

splitviewcontroller->

> -Master(UITabbarController) -> first Tab (navigation controller) -> root (custom class) with show detail segue to Detail (navigation
>   controller)
>
> -Detail (navigation controller) -> root (custom class)

I don't have enough rep to post pictures, any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated

[EDIT]
Here's a [snapshot](http://s28.postimg.org/bhbyzm7ot/Screen_Shot_2015_05_12_at_3_42_29_PM.png) of my storyboard with some annotations

Comment: You can use http://postimage.org/ to upload images, then insert a link for the image.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jessica , I uploaded the picture of my storyboard with some annotations: [link](http://s28.postimg.org/bhbyzm7ot/Screen_Shot_2015_05_12_at_3_42_29_PM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that the root controller for my master controller of the split controller, was a UITabbar. I solved it with a navigation controller with the tabbar as its root controller